# MIME file attachment is not opening

Tags: php, email, pear, mime

My code is

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php"; // PEAR Mail package
require_once ('Mail/mime.php'); // PEAR Mail_Mime packge 

 $from = "<meenu.spiralbean@gmail.com>";
 $to = "<meenu.spiralbean@gmail.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";


$host = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "example@gmail.com";
$password = "example";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
   'port' => $port,
  'auth' => true,
  'username' => $username,
  'password' => $password));


$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);


 // attachment
 $file = '/var/www/html/formsubmit/TodoList/upload/abc.pdf';
 $crlf = "n";
 $text="Helllooooo";
 $html = "<html> <head> <title>Mail test</title> </head>  <body>something</body></html>";

$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
if($mime->addAttachment($file))
{
   echo "Success";
}
else 

{
    echo "Failed";
}


$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);


$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
 echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

The attachment is unable to open even after downloading it.

Mail is coming in inbox and attachment is also there.But the attachment seems like txt file.but I am actually attaching a pdf file. I used SMTP mail and MIME mail functions.

Pls help me.

Comment: The code looks about right. Can you please add the source of the email (MIME source) as received by the recipient to your question?

Comment: i didn't get you. Pls make it clear

Comment: The code appears to be correct, so it does not really tell us what goes wrong with the email. The email "source code" (a.k.a. the MIME source or the .EML file) may provide useful clues, however. Assuming the recipient mailbox is at Gmail, you can use the `Show Original` menu to get the email source. Other email clients usually provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code in the mail is:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
 name=abc.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=abc.pdf;
 size=4997278
```

The content type is a generic one; try to use `application/pdf` as second parameter to [`addAttachment()`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addattachment.php).

---

Also, NEVER post your real mail address and password anywhere.